# Recursively call a function in Java which creates new objects

Tags: java, recursion

If in a function which is getting called recursively with smaller arguments and within this function we are creating an object of a class. The objects created recursively will have the same name, hence we cannot preserve the name uniqueness. How can we handle such cases in Java?

Comment: Do you have a code-example?

Comment: Objects don't have names. Variables have names, but they also have a scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question stems from a misunderstanding. In Java, the name you give to a local variable is 100% irrelevant at the time the code runs - the only purpose is for you, the programmer, to specify which variable you are talking about (by giving its name, and having the compiler figure out what you mean by looking in the local scope, the scope above it and so on).

So, if you have a recursive method that calls itself, and in this method declare variables that hold new objects, then there is no clash as far as Java is concerned and they will all correctly refer to distinct objects in distinct places in memory.

---

If you actually meant 'I want to record all the new objects I make in my recursive method, but have them be distinctly referable to', then start by making a collection (`ArrayList` for example) one of the parameters to your recursive method - then you can add all newly made objects to this collection and when it fully returns, it will be full of your newly made objects. But if that's not distinguishing enough, then you need to ask 'what would distinguish these objects?' which will depend upon what the object is for (should some parameter of the recursive method be part of the 'name"? some other state? or does it just need to be random and unique?).

Comment: You are right. But the asker wants to access the old objects too

Comment: @shiladitya: where do you find such a request in the question?

Comment: that is what i inferred. otherwise the question did not make sense :)